rustgpu how do you declare an image storage?
I am trying to declare an image input that can be written to by the fragment shader for voxelizing geometry.
I have the following:
#![cfg_attr(target_arch = "spirv", no_std, feature(lang_items))]
#![allow(internal_features)]

extern crate bytemuck;
extern crate spirv_std;

use spirv_std::{arch::IndexUnchecked, glam::*, image::*, num_traits::Float, spirv};

type Texture2D = Image!(2D, type=f32, sampled);
type SampledTexture2D = SampledImage<Texture2D>;
type Storage3D = Image!(3D, type=f32, sampled=false);

#[spirv(fragment)]
pub fn main_fs(
    in_position: Vec3,
    in_uv: Vec3,
    #[spirv(descriptor_set = 1, binding = 1)] images: &[SampledTexture2D; 69],
    #[spirv(descriptor_set = 1, binding = 3)] volume: &Storage3D,
)
{
    let index = in_uv.z.round() as usize;
    let mut albedo = unsafe { images.index_unchecked(index).sample(in_uv.xy()) };

    albedo.w = 1.;

    let coords = in_position * 512.0;
    unsafe {
        volume.write(
            IVec3::new(coords.x as i32, coords.y as i32, coords.z as i32),
            albedo,
        )
    };
}

The problem with this snippet is that it crashes with this error:
error: error:0:0 - Capability StorageImageWriteWithoutFormat is required to write to storage image
             OpImageWrite %109 %106 %107
      |
      = note: spirv-val failed
      = note: module `/home/makogan/rust_never_engine/examples/09_voxel_tracing/voxelization_shader/target/spirv-unknown-vulkan1.2/release/deps/voxelization_shader.spvs/main_fs.

What is the correct declaration of image storage objects with rustgpu?
